# Can an approximation be “lifted”?

Tags: verbs, nouns

Let's say we make some approximation in some theory (such as there being no friction, when in fact there is).

Now we want to remove this approximation, and thus improve the real-world meaning of the theory.

Is it correct to say this?

> This approximation can easily be lifted by (whatever, adding whatnot constant to whatnot formula on whatnot page).

Any alternatives?

Comment: Assumption or approximation?

Comment: @JAM I didn't even notice that at first. Now I'm not sure what's being asked.

Comment: @JAM Sorry, I meant approximation. Fixed.

Comment: I think "removed" would be much clearer in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, approximations can be lifted. **To lift** carries the sense of *remove* or *annul*, as in *lifting an embargo*.

The usage is common in technical papers. These are the [Google Scholar results](http://scholar.google.co.in/scholar?hl=en&q=This+%22approximation+can+be+lifted%22&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C5&as_sdtp=) which use *lift* along with *approximation*.

Comment: Actually, your Google Scholar search returns only 15 papers, three of which are by the same author.  I would say that it demonstrates quite the opposite — that such usage is not common.

Answer (score 2):

I've never heard of an approximation being *lifted*.  I would say instead that some phenomena (e.g. friction, Coriolis force, relativity) can be **corrected for**.  You can **apply a correction factor** if the refinement is multiplicative or **add a correction term** if it's additive.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think 'lifted' is the word you want here. Once you remove or negate your assumption, providing instead real data, you can ['**refine**'](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/REFINED) or ['**improve**'](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/improve?s=t) your calculations, turning your approximation into an exact answer.

Comment: But isn't "refine" or "improve" rather weird? To me, it means that the approximation is still in place--just improved or refined.

Comment: You can say you refine or improve your working theory when you remove the approximation or assumption. It would also make sense if you're laying our an argument for something, then refining that argument by addressing possible objections.

Answer (score 1):

You may write for example

> Without this approximation/assumption, the conclusion still holds if you add this constant to that formula.